# Starting interactive command on shell started using netcat -e hangs

Tags: linux, tcp, ftp

I have not gotten the time to thoroughly investigate how netcat starts a specified command using the -e option, however I believe that it achieves this by forking itself, it then sets the standard input output of the forked process to the connected socket, and then executes the command using exec. If this were the case, would it not mean that if I start the ftp client using a shell started with nc -e /bin/sh, it would inherit the standard input and output of the shell which is currently the tcp socket connection? This would mean that ftp should not hang would it not? Or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

The FTP client used was netkit-ftp while the netcat used was the default netcat installed in Kali Rolling.

Comment: The version of nc I have doesn't have a 'e' flag, but one BSD it apparently sets IPSEC options. ( http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?nc ) . How the ftp client will behave depends on *which* ftp client it is and how your invoke it - but you've not provided any details of that.

Comment: @symcbean Edited to include versions of software used.